# Does it help to have a Linux frame of mind for being a better embedded programmer?

Tags: linux, embedded, beagleboard

was wondering - if knowing **The Linux way of life or the Linux architecture**, would give a better frame of mind for programming on embedded devices especially when they have some kind of OS in them.
Just want to be sure that I did not miss a major thing :)

Note:
I come from a windows background, can program in C and C++.
Passionate and finally want to get started into Embedded programming. I would like to start by doing typical hobbyists project at home.

It would be nice if anyone would also comment on BeagleBoard as a starting point for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Mostly yes.

Lundin correctly described the "two worlds of embedded" (although the border between them is very fuzzy).

If you're writing for "higher embedded", like Android, or other devices that run Linux, then definitely expert knowledge of Linux will be of much help. You still need to know some "bare bones" and don't get scared when you see the likes of `&=~` operator in C, but knowing Linux - the Linux of the old, where you configured stuff by editing files in `/etc`, where you compiled your own kernels for everyday use, where you would build software from tarballs, that's what helps. Knowing modern Linux - Gnome, gconf-editor, Synaptic and the likes will not be of much help.

Then next, if you're programming devices without OS, in the middle area - fast and strong enough to run C programs, but not the OS, you still need Linux. Because crosscompile. You don't need actual Linux. Cygwin is okay for that. MinGW may suffice. Still, you will probably need to be able to build your own crosscompiler (based on GCC), linker, debugger, make tools, and the rest of "backbone" of the IDE. Unless your chip supplier is awesome and provides a complete toolchain with IDE.

Only when you're into tiny processors, you don't need Linux. Stuff like car alarm remote, christmas lights blinker, car tire pressure sensor, battery level monitor - stuff that can have 16 bytes RAM, 1KB EEPROM, and the rest of CPU to match, you will need to use an IDE that works with this CPU, no OS, no C compiler, nothing remotely close to Linux - the IDE will most likely be Windows based.

Comment: Yes and no. Mostly no, IMO and 22 years experience.  But that's just an opinion, and that 22 years was probably in just one of the two worlds.  Otherwise great answer!

Answer (score 3):

"Embedded" is a fuzzy word. There are two categories:

There are realtime embedded systems: microcontroller/microprocessor applications that are intimately communicating directly with the hardware on a low abstraction level. Typical applications are control systems/automation, industrial, automotive, medtech, household electronics, data/telecom communications etc.

And then there are fluffy embedded systems: various laptop:ish computers, embedded linux, embedded windows, phones and phoney operative systems, anything involving internet, human-machine intefaces etc.

People working in both categories will firmly state that they are working with embedded systems, while the latter kind are often just doing another flavour of desktop applications. Depending on which category you are aiming for, Linux may or may not be a merit. The telecom branch for example, overlaps both of these categories, and they are often using embedded Linux even for non-fluffy applications.

In either case, *nix may be used as the development platform, so knowing it won't hurt.

Comment: so is it worth investing time in Linux before starting learning embedded ?

Comment: by the way I am interested in the first kind of applications you mentioned _"control systems/automation, industrial, automotive, medtech..."_

Comment: @vijiboy In that case Linux is rather useless knowledge. Study  electronics and assembler.

Comment: @Lundin did you mean there will be no OS in kind of apps I am interested.  I feel having an OS frees you of many important tasks like memory pool mgmt., threading / multitasking, device I/O etc. one of my application (machine vision application) ideally would use 3-4 threads and heavy memory operations

Comment: @viljiboy: even if you had an OS for this kind of application, if you are serious about a career you need to learn these topics (memory management, threading, I/O, ...). And the best way to learn would be to do it yourself, at least to begin with. I wonder what category @Lundin will say that machine vision application belongs to...

Comment: @vijiboy Oh sure there will be an OS in a lot of them, but it will most likely be a RTOS, and not some sluggish overkill Linux. I believe machine vision mainly belongs to the industry automation branch, meaining most applications where it is implemented will be realtime systems.

Comment: 2 of the 5 best known RTOS are *nix based architecture [as per wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). So I think knowing Linux will definitely help in my embedded journey. please also see links in my answer

Comment: @vijiboy It also names Windows CE as one of them, so that should give you a hint of what Wikipedia is worth. If you don't start to giggle as soon as you hear "embedded windows", that's a bad sign if you intend to work with realtime systems.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you really do not need to know Linux for embedded programming. Many companies developing embedded software do it on windows and have no contact with other OS.

But sure, knowing more makes you more versatile, and general knowledge makes you a better engineer. This includes different OS as many other things.

When it comes to BeagleBoard, it depends on the kind of application you are interested in. 
If you want to understand the low-level, I would start on a simpler processor and learn how to use peripherals, hardware interrupts, debouncing signals... There is an educational point in doing this yourself some time.

I suppose you can also skip that and start with an ARM-A8 and possibly an embedded OS, it's just not the path I followed.

Comment: thanks, but does it really help in a significant way rather than just increasing your overall knowledge. e.g. if in my coming career most of the embedded projects will be having some flavor of linux then its better to know it before hand.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: in my experience no you do not need Linux knowledge (since you wrote that embedded OS was not a concern, I'm assuming that you mean as development environment). But my experience is by definition in the past, I don't know what is going to happen. I worked with a chip that had only Windows as supported development environment, not long ago. I don't think vendors are going to have environments that don't support Windows.

Comment: If you are thinking of a possible coming career, why not look up what companies that could be of interest for you are using?

Comment: you mean I can continue on windows supported chips without any problem. I really wanted to know if in case I learnt Linux, am I really going to be benefited (not in the general sense but in many specific ways as many OS's belong to Linux Culture or the Linux way of life) ...

Answer (score 1):

What I am about to say may cause a flame war, but...

I have found that Linux is a much more productive development environment than Windows. At my previous job, we were developing firmware for managed switches and industrial automation equipment, which ran an embedded Linux operating system. All the developers had both Windows and Linux boxes, as the user interface software only ran on Windows. We all used Linux for developing, though, as it was simply easier.

At my current job, the only choice is to run Windows, but to make it more productive we are running [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), which provides a Linux-like environment. It is very difficult to develop software on Windows that is not specifically for Windows.

As for developing for an embedded system without an OS... I have an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) that I play with occasionally. I have programmed it both from Windows and Linux, and have found the experiences fairly similar. Using Arduino's own tools, Windows seems to run a bit more smoothly, but if you want to hack on it and make something interesting, you're better off using Linux.

Personally (and this will likely provoke some nasty comments), I feel that Linux is best for doing productive work, and Windows is best for playing games.

So basically, this all boils down to this: Try using Linux for developing your project. You will probably find it to be a much smoother, more productive experience. If you don't like it, you don't have to keep using it. But the experience will probably be worth it.

Edit (due to question rewording): Knowing the "Linux way of life" is unlikely to help much when coding for an embedded project that is not running Linux itself. As I understand it, the Unix philosophy is about two main issues:

1. Each tool should do one thing and do it well (don't make something that tries to be everything).
2. Whenever possible, data should be plain text (allows for simple piping through processes and searching for content).

If you are working on a system without an operating system, you are writing code for a compiler and not likely working with a full shell at any point. You also are unlike to have any sort of file system. So both of these points are moot; you are not likely to gain anything concretely related to embedded programming by studying Linux, although it certainly couldn't hurt :-)

Comment: sorry if the question was misunderstood, I have re-framed the question to be more clear. actually wanted to know - if knowing _The Linux way of life_ is a good frame of mind for being a better embedded programmer especially when we have an OS on the device.

Comment: @Jonathan You are really referring to the tool chain here. It ain't Windows/Linux fault if some particular hardware has poor support for the specific desktop OS. There are no dependencies between your embedded target and the desktop OS. Such dependencies are created by the tool chain: compiler/debugger/emulator/test tools etc.

Comment: @Lundin I never said anything about hardware support or dependencies... I just said the experience was smoother here or there.

Comment: If your target is "CPU X" and the only feasible tool to use is "Tool Y for Z OS", then use "Z OS", simple as that. Not many tools come with both Windows and Linux support.

Comment: Compilers are one exception, though. There is a compiler for virtually every CPU available for virtually every platform. There may be the occasional missing piece, but it's rare. He wants to use a BeagleBoard, which has an ARM CPU. There is great support for that on Linux, just need to `apt-get install` or `yum install` the appropriate compiler. What would you suggest he do for that on Windows? Microsoft's compiler collection certainly doesn't support it...

Comment: @Jonathan You will likely have plenty of ARM compilers to pick from, as it's the current mainstream hype. The traditional embedded compiler companies like Greenhills, IAR etc will have ARM tools running on Windows. I'm not sure if they have Linux versions of their tools. Microsoft will obviously not have any embedded system compilers, for the same reasons Coca Cola won't have them either.

Comment: Okay, so we're back to "Use whatever fits your needs best. I suggest Linux because I like it." :-)

Answer (score 0):

I really think if you want to learn a little about embedded sphere you should not start by using an OS directly. Prefer to have hands on a small low level project then add an OS if it's really needed for your final application.

I don't think setting up an OS into an embedded device will be easier than starting from scratch. It will bring you some functionalities (that I am not sure you really need to learn embedded) but it will bring you lot of hard debugging time in case of problems in the OS port.

Comment: thanks. one of my project demands threading (3-4 threads) so do you think I can do without an OS at that time

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing embedded programming for 10 years, currently for networking equipment and before that Apache helicopters.  Both companies had POSIX-like operating systems on the target, but not embedded Linux directly.  My current company uses mostly Windows for individual developer environments.  However, we do have a few Linux boxes hanging around for special purposes.  My previous company used a mix of Windows and Sun Solaris Unix. So wherever you go, you may not use Unix or Linux on your day to day computer, but you are likely to come across it at least occasionally.

On the other hand, I've known developers who have programmed on Linux for embedded Linux targets their entire careers.  It really depends on the company, as smaller or newer companies have a tendency to use Linux more than corporations.  However, using embedded forms of Windows on targets is very rare in my experience.  I know devices are out there, but I've never personally met a developer who worked on one.

Anyway, Linux is free to use and has other benefits besides being good for a job.  There's really no downside to giving it a try for a couple of months, other than giving up some of your time.

Comment: sorry if the question was misunderstood, I have re-framed the question to be more clear. actually wanted to know if knowing _The Linux way of life_ is a good frame of mind for being a better embedded programmer

Answer (score 0):

Linux is growing in embedded...  see latest research:
[Top 10 trends for the embedded software and tools market in 2011 - VDC research](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/News/VDC-Research-2011-embeded-trend-predictions/)
[Android Becomes Number One in U.S. Smartphone Market Share](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/Android_number_one_in_us_smartphone_market_share.php)

Knowing the *Linux way of life* will definitely be a plus in embedded domain provided the kind of apps you are interested in are contained in the above mentioned links.

Comment: Those links are mainly about the "fluffy embedded systems" category, however. Fluffy is definitely going strong right now, with the current smartphone hype. If you want to work with smartphones, knowing Linux and Android will no doubt be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

understanding Linux architecture will be over kill (although basic overview is good) before just starting in embedded field

e.g. to cut a tree you don't have to invent an axe - just start using one, then gradually you could learn to sharpen the axe

Its better to get started small - get hands-on, and focus on specific areas as is the need of the hour. grow with your work and work keeping your goals in mind

you will surely gain much faster and not get stuck in self loop - R&D to do R&D  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want to embed Linux! And as an embedded systems developer of some 22 years, I would suggest that Linux is unsuitable and unnecessary for a very large proportion of embedded systems projects.

Understanding the workings of an RTOS, and real-time priority based pre-emptive scheduling and IPC mechanisms would stand you in better stead.  Take a look at [this](http://www.eetimes.com/electrical-engineers/education-training/courses/4213896/Fundamentals-of--Real-Time-Operating-Systems) for example.

Comment: thanks! I will go through the link. seems a good presentation on RTOS and rationale behind it.